# PHP file path error

Tags: php, path

I have this problem:
I have a database with All namefile uploaded in; so, Ι made a query to get the file name and its extension saved as TEXT but when Ι try to see the image in HTML don't show anything.

My code is like this:
`<img src = "<?php echo $profileImage; ?>"></img>`

The `$profileImage` var contains the path for Reach the image. If I try to change the `$profileImage` with the path of the image, everything works even if the var contains the same thing of the string.

Comment: try to **debug**  first with echo $profileImage value, like `echo $profileImage;` and check what exactly you get.....

Comment: So, what would you like us to do? You told us what's wrong and what works; where's your code?

Comment: I try and the path Is correct

Comment: Show us the path that `$profileImage` is printing

Comment: datatable/users/luca.bodini.1/profile.jpg

Comment: perhaps deal with the image from the root directory like: `/datatable/users/luca.bodini.1/profile.jpg` its difficult to know what your file structure is

Comment: You need to provide us with the actual codes you're using for both methods including how they're stored in DB. Post that in your question and NOT in the comments area. So far, this is guesswork.

Comment: Please delete `</img>`. I think it does not solve your problem but internet will be better place. img tag does not have end tag as for example div has.

Comment: @lucabodd I've posted an answer below. If that doesn't work, let me know. If it doesn't serve your purpose, I will simply delete it. If it does work, then accept it as being correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here, either try:

```
<img src = "<?php echo "/path_to/image_files/" .$profileImage; ?>">
```

or

```
<img src = "<?php echo "/" .$profileImage; ?>">
```

One of those will work, or modify accordingly.

Since you haven't provided us with any other **required** information.

The `/` tells the server to go to the root and fetch the image path from there.

You may be trying to access those files outside different folders.

Sidenote: `</img>` is not a valid tag. You can safely remove it from your code.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

- *Plus*, view your HTML source to see how it's being populated from your database.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing your code or how the data is stored in the database we can't really help.

Try view the html source code in the web browser, and look for the content of the $profileImage